# Get time/date range of selected timespan apex area chart

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, apexcharts

I have some issues with apex charts. I want to create an area chart with a selectable time range on the x-axis (standard by selecting an interval by `mousedraw`). The "standard" example is doing what I want. But now I want to calculate with the parameters which are selected by `mousedraw` and write the results in a `div` tag.

My question is how to get the selected time range (to visualize) and the appropriate values?

The following code is the standard example from apex charts for area charts.

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
    <div id="chart">
        <div class="toolbar">
          <button id="one_month">
            Heute
          </button>
          <button id="Letzter Tag">
            Gestern
          </button>
          <button id="one_year" class="active">
            letzte Woche
          </button>
          <button id="ytd">
            Dieser Monat
          </button>
          <button id="all">
            letztes Halbjahr
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="chart-timeline"></div>
      </div>
    <script>
        var options = {
            series: [{
          name: 'Energiekonsum',
          data: [
            [1671578047000,0.073 ],
[1671578947000,0.037 ],
[1671579847000,0.049 ],
          ]
        },
          chart: {
          id: 'area-datetime',
          type: 'area',
          height: 350,
          zoom: {
            autoScaleYaxis: false
          }
        },
        annotations: {
          yaxis: [{
            y: 30,
            borderColor: '#999',
            label: {
              show: true,
              text: 'Durchschnittsverbrauch',
              style: {
                color: "#fff",
                background: '#00E396'
              }
            }
          }],
          xaxis: [{
            x: new Date('14 Nov 2012').getTime(),
            borderColor: '#999',
            yAxisIndex: 0,
            label: {
              show: true,
              text: 'Rally',
              style: {
                color: "#fff",
                background: '#775DD0'
              }
            }
          }]
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        markers: {
          size: 0,
          style: 'hollow',
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          min: new Date('01 Mar 2012').getTime(),
          tickAmount: 6,
        },
        tooltip: {
          x: {
            format: 'dd MMM yyyy'
          }
        },
        fill: {
          type: 'gradient',
          gradient: {
            shadeIntensity: 1,
            opacityFrom: 0.7,
            opacityTo: 0.9,
            stops: [0, 100]
          }
        },
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart-timeline"), options);
        chart.render();
      
      
        var resetCssClasses = function(activeEl) {
        var els = document.querySelectorAll('button')
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
          el.classList.remove('active')
        })
      
        activeEl.target.classList.add('active')
      }
      
      document
        .querySelector('#one_month')
        .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          resetCssClasses(e)
      
          chart.zoomX(
            new Date('28 Jan 2013').getTime(),
            new Date('27 Feb 2013').getTime()
          )
        })
      
      document
        .querySelector('#six_months')
        .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          resetCssClasses(e)
      
          chart.zoomX(
            new Date('27 Sep 2012').getTime(),
            new Date('27 Feb 2013').getTime()
          )
        })
      
      document
        .querySelector('#one_year')
        .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          resetCssClasses(e)
          chart.zoomX(
            new Date('27 Feb 2012').getTime(),
            new Date('27 Feb 2013').getTime()
          )
        })
      
      document.querySelector('#ytd').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        resetCssClasses(e)
      
        chart.zoomX(
          new Date('01 Jan 2013').getTime(),
          new Date('27 Feb 2013').getTime()
        )
      })
      
      document.querySelector('#all').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        resetCssClasses(e)
      
        chart.zoomX(
          new Date('23 Jan 2012').getTime(),
          new Date('27 Feb 2013').getTime()
        )
      })
      
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, I think you need to enable **selection** on your chart and use its **event** function to get time range (`xaxis`) and values (`yaxis`). Inside this function, you can also write the data to a `div`.

Take a look at this example and play with selections (see icon at the top right corner of the chart):

```js
const selection = document.querySelector('#selection');

let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    data: [
      [new Date('2022-12-28'), 100],
      [new Date('2022-12-29'), 200],
      [new Date('2022-12-30'), 150]
    ]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    height: 350,
    toolbar: {
      show: true,
      tools: {
        selection: true,
        zoom: false,
        zoomin: false,
        zoomout: false,
        pan: false,
        reset: false,
        download: false
      }
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: false
    },
    selection: {
      enabled: true,
      type: 'xy'
    },
    events: {
      selection: (chartContext, { xaxis, yaxis }) => {
        yaxis = Array.isArray(yaxis) ? { min: yaxis[0].min, max: yaxis[0].max } : yaxis;
      
        selection.innerHTML = `<strong>xaxis →</strong> min: <span class="min">${new Date(xaxis.min).toISOString()}</span> | max: <span class="max">${new Date(xaxis.max).toISOString()}</span><br><strong>yaxis →</strong> min: <span class="min">${yaxis.min}</span> | max: <span class="max">${yaxis.max}</span>`
      }
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```css
.min {
  color: green;
}

.max {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="selection"></div>
```

To avoid getting `undefined` for `yaxis.min` and `yaxis.max` on mouse up in this particular example, I added this line of code:

```js
yaxis = Array.isArray(yaxis) ? { min: yaxis[0].min, max: yaxis[0].max } : yaxis;
```

This is a bit odd, but when you release the mouse button while selecting something, `yaxis` is not an object literal as usual but it is an array. Could it be a bug?